# Partial sum in a group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

### I have a table (more tables but the join is not a prob) filled with the hours made by every dip. I want to calculate the sum everyday of the working hour for every dip.
The "table" is like:

- Name -- hours -- date -

---

- Jon    - 2 - 1/1/2000 -
- Jon    - 3 - 1/1/2000 -
- Bob    - 6 - 1/1/2000 -
- Jon    - 2 - 2/1/2000 -
- Jon    - 4 - 2/1/2000 -

what I want is

- Jon    - 5 - 1/1/2000 -
- Bob    - 6 - 1/1/2000 -
- Jon    - 6 - 2/1/2000 -

I think of some double group by, but I don't know how..
Until now I have used a simple sum at the end of month (
SELECT id, sum(EFFORT) /8 AS GG
FROM table as CA
where [CANC_DATE] is null
)
but this generate some trouble when the worker is a part-time or do some extra-hours. I have added the goup by on date after the where (group by date) but I get the sum of all workers in that day.

Sorry about it, but i am a frontend developer relocated to db programming and i have only university level preparation (maybe 20y ago)

Comment: It would be much to your benefit to add the appropriate language tag to this question.  SQL, probably?  Also, it will be much better received if you present a *bona fide* attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL statement:

```
Select name, date, sum(hours) from table group by name, date.
```

Comment: Note that you also probably want to add an ORDER BY name, date at the end of that statement to give you the results in that order